# BSOD Before Windows Will Loads - Graphics Related

Tags: windows-7, bsod, troubleshooting, nvidia-graphics-card

Alright deep breath here:

(Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit btw)

Today I installed Star Craft 2 Beta.  After trying to log in, it had some issues where it said my device stopped working (referring to my video device I have to imagine).  After I force quit the game there were some random "hot" (various colors if i remember correctly) pixels on the screen.  I decided to reboot and try again with similar results.

I figured that maybe my display drivers could stand to be updated (I don't frequently update them as I don't often run into problems).  I went out to nVidia's website and grabbed the latest drivers for Windows 7 64 bit GeForce 9 series.  (I have SLi-ed 9800 GTs).  Everything seemed to install fine and I performed the restart.

This is when things went from bad (can't play SC2 beta ;) ) to worse (can't boot into windows!).

Initially the very first splash screen - I think it's the bios splash screen - had lines of colored pixels covering it.  It then displayed a screen that had lots of "(" on it.  After that it showed the normal windows 7 splash screen as if it were going to load into Windows.  Before getting much further, it BSODed on me.

It was a 0x0000003B stop error.  At nvlddmkm.sys.  A little digging let verified that this was a problem with an nVidia graphics device, not a real shocker.

Windows decided it would try to help me diagnose the problem, which it's only answer to was a System Restore, which did nothing to alleviate the problem.

I was able to boot up fine in safe mode and was not able to roll back the driver, however I did uninstall the driver and reboot.  I still had the graphical anomalies during the first two screens (same colored "."'s and weird "("'s), but there was NOT a stop error.

Windows loaded up, found a default driver for the device and installed it and I restarted to let it load - and had yet another BSOD Stop error.

Repeat driver uninstall, this time I reloaded the same version (I *think* it's possible that I was running a 32 bit version or a vista versus windows 7 version, but I don't have that information handy) of the nVidia driver from their website.

Restart, same anomalies, same Stop Error.

I am at a loss - At this point all I can think is that the firmware for the Video cards got fried or there's actual damage to the cards which I sincerely hope is not the case but the sooner I know the better.

Any insight into what I might be able to do to troubleshoot/fix this problem would be most helpful.

Attached below is a dump from DxDiag.

Please let me know if there is more info that I could provide.

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 3/18/2010, 23:22:48
       Machine name: BRIAN-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7600) (7600.win7_rtm.090713-1255)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc
       System Model: XPS 630i
               BIOS: Phoenix - AwardBIOS v6.00PG
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q8200  @ 2.33GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8190MB RAM
          Page File: 1855MB used, 14521MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7600.16385 32bit Unicode
  DxDiag Previously: Crashed in DirectShow (stage 1). Re-running DxDiag with "dontskip" command line parameter or choosing not to bypass information gathering when prompted might result in DxDiag successfully obtaining this information

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: 
       Manufacturer: 
          Chip type: 
           DAC type: 
         Device Key: Enum\
     Display Memory: n/a
   Dedicated Memory: n/a
      Shared Memory: n/a
       Current Mode: 1600 x 1200 (32 bit) (1Hz)
        Driver Name: 
Driver File Version:  ()
     Driver Version: 
        DDI Version: unknown
       Driver Model: unknown
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: , 0 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: n/a
    WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
  Device Identifier: {D7B70EE0-4340-11CF-B123-B03DAEC2CB35}
          Vendor ID: 0x0000
          Device ID: 0x0000
          SubSys ID: 0x00000000
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: Unknown
     Rank Of Driver: Unknown
        Video Accel: 
      Deinterlace Caps: n/a
       D3D9 Overlay: n/a
            DXVA-HD: n/a
       DDraw Status: Not Available
         D3D Status: Not Available
         AGP Status: Not Available

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0888&SUBSYS_10280249&REV_1001
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.5667 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 8/18/2008 04:05:28, 1485592 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0888&SUBSYS_10280249&REV_1001
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.5667 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 8/18/2008 04:05:28, 1485592 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Realtek HDMI Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0888&SUBSYS_10280249&REV_1001
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.5667 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 8/18/2008 04:05:28, 1485592 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

---------------------
Sound Capture Devices
---------------------
            Description: Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)
  Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.5667 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 8/18/2008 04:05:28, 1485592 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0

            Description: Realtek Digital Input (Realtek High Definition Audio)
  Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.5667 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 8/18/2008 04:05:28, 1485592 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0

-------------------
DirectInput Devices
-------------------
      Device Name: Mouse
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Keyboard
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: ESA FW Update
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: 0x0
Vendor/Product ID: 0x0955, 0x000A
        FF Driver: n/a

Poll w/ Interrupt: No

-----------
USB Devices
-----------
+ USB Root Hub
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x10DE, 0x026D
| Matching Device ID: usb\root_hub
| Service: usbhub
| 
+-+ USB Input Device
| | Vendor/Product ID: 0x0955, 0x000A
| | Location: Port_#0002.Hub_#0001
| | Matching Device ID: generic_hid_device
| | Service: HidUsb
| | 
| +-+ HID-compliant device
| | | Vendor/Product ID: 0x0955, 0x000A
| | | Matching Device ID: hid_device
| | 
+-+ USB Input Device
| | Vendor/Product ID: 0x046D, 0xC01E
| | Location: Port_#0003.Hub_#0001
| | Matching Device ID: generic_hid_device
| | Service: HidUsb
| | 
| +-+ HID-compliant mouse
| | | Vendor/Product ID: 0x046D, 0xC01E
| | | Matching Device ID: hid_device_system_mouse
| | | Service: mouhid

----------------
Gameport Devices
----------------

------------
PS/2 Devices
------------
+ Standard PS/2 Keyboard
| Matching Device ID: *pnp0303
| Service: i8042prt
| 
+ Terminal Server Keyboard Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_kbd
| Upper Filters: kbdclass
| Service: TermDD
| 
+ Terminal Server Mouse Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_mou
| Upper Filters: mouclass
| Service: TermDD

------------------------
Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives
------------------------
      Drive: C:
 Free Space: 324.3 GB
Total Space: 608.4 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WDC WD64 00AAKS-75A7B SCSI Disk Device

      Drive: D:
 Free Space: 1.0 GB
Total Space: 2.0 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WDC WD64 00AAKS-75A7B SCSI Disk Device

      Drive: E:
      Model: TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-H653F SCSI CdRom Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7600.16385 (English), , 0 bytes

--------------
System Devices
--------------
     Name: PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B7&SUBSYS_000010DE&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&18
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AF&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&0A
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03A3&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A2\3&2411E6FE&1&00
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA nForce Serial ATA Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0267&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&78
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B6&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&10
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AE&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&09
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0272&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&52
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA nForce Serial ATA Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0266&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&70
   Driver: n/a

     Name: LSI 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_11C1&DEV_5811&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_70\4&14591D7E&0&2880
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B5&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&06
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AD&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&08
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0270&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A2\3&2411E6FE&1&48
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0265&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&68
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT 
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0605&SUBSYS_062D10DE&REV_A2\4&4BABE2A&0&0028
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B4&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&07
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AC&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&01
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_026F&SUBSYS_CB8410DE&REV_A2\3&2411E6FE&1&80
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA nForce PCI System Management
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0264&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&51
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT 
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0605&SUBSYS_062D10DE&REV_A2\4&10BD3C89&0&0018
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B3&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&0E
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AB&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&04
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_026E&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&59
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard ISA bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0260&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&50
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03BC&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&11
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B2&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&0D
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03AA&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&02
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_026D&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&58
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03BA&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&12
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B1&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&0C
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03A9&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&03
   Driver: n/a

     Name: High Definition Audio Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_026C&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A2\3&2411E6FE&1&81
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B8&SUBSYS_000010DE&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&28
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03B0&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A1\3&2411E6FE&1&0B
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard RAM Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03A8&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A2\3&2411E6FE&1&05
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0269&SUBSYS_02491028&REV_A3\3&2411E6FE&1&A0
   Driver: n/a

---------------
EVR Power Information
---------------
Current Setting: {5C67A112-A4C9-483F-B4A7-1D473BECAFDC} (Quality) 
  Quality Flags: 2576
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow half deinterlace
    Allow scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 100
  Balanced Flags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 50
  PowerFlags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 0
```